# Input resistor to BJT base > ground resistor, why?

Tags: resistors, ground, logic-gates

Thank you for your time.

I'm new to electronics and so this question might, to you, call for an evident answer. Nevertheless, I can't seem to find that answer.

I've stumbled upon a schematic for a BJT-only, 4-bit computer. When I look at the XOR gate that's part of the first full-adder (only shown here), I see that R5, which connects the Q4 base input to ground is 10 times smaller than R6. Won't that sink most of the current? Because the base doesn't need much to saturate, I understand that it could still be enough; but I wonder: why is this configuration desired?

(You can see the same configuration on R8 and R13)

[image: from waitingforfriday.com]

Thanks again!

Comment: Resistor-Transistor logic is mostly dead these days.  Anyway, your observation is correct, and there will be some static power loss there, but the analysis is more concerned with voltage levels than currents.  In logic, transistors are conceptually treated as voltage switches, not current multipliers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resistor-Transistor logic is mostly dead these days.  Anyway, your observation is correct, and there will be some static power loss there, but the analysis is more concerned with voltage levels than currents.

In logic, transistors are conceptually treated as voltage switches, not current multipliers.

To allow the designer to mentally keep track of a large amount of logic, he tends to work with blocks corresponding to logic gates, not individual transistors and resistors.  R5 is, along with R3, R4, Q2, and Q3, part of an AND gate.  R6 is part of an OR gate along with R7, R8, Q4, and Q5.  No one bothered to perform optimization of component values across adjacent stages -- the only consideration given to the resistor values will be to make the input impedance much higher than the output impedance of the previous stage, whether or not that is actually needed.

By using gate-level circuit blocks, the designer only has to verify that each gate functions correctly for the various local input voltages.  If he tries to optimize across the entire circuit, significant static power savings could be achieved, but the load currents may depend on additional signals and the complexity of the analysis grows exponentially.

TTL and CMOS logic families improve considerably on the behavior causing you concern, because the pull-down is built with a transistor as well and able to switch open when not needed, thus minimizing waste current.

Answer (score 1):

That design is not 'desired' as much as it is simplistic. By normalizing resistors to values such as 1, 10, 100, 1K, 10K, etc, it makes the math simple. R5 is 1K, so it sinks < 4mA if Q2 and Q3 are ON. It also provides a low impedance source to drive Q4 low quickly if Q2 or Q3 are OFF.
 All of the resistors value could double and this circuit would work just fine, but with a slightly slower response. Many of the 10K resistors could be 4.7K and the circuit would work just a bit faster, with slightly more current consumed.
 Even with all the 1K pull-down resistors, this circuit consumes only 8 to 15mA of current, a very small amount. As per Ben Voigt's comment, these transistors are seen as voltage switches to drive RTL logic. The resistors provide proper bias currents for the transistors to work as switches.